# How to open port 9090 for cockpit for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, cockpit

I am trying to get cockpit for Linux running on a new Ubuntu (22.04) VPS. I've installed firewall-cmd, added the port 9090 , disabled ufw, opened it on oracle cloud & netstat says it is listening on port 9090. But when I load it up it cannot load the page (address unreachable). Using curl localhost:9090 shows the correct code, so I know it is something firewall. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the iptables? and have maybe try to tcp ping the port to double check that it is open?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).